# Android finish activity and reload the previously activity

Tags: android

I have activities A -> B -> C.
I finish the activity C and when it destroyed I want automatically reload the activity B.

Help pls.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may start activity C with the following.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.C, 0);
```

Then, when C is finished you may do whatever you want with the following:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data){
     reload();
     //OR
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.B,0);
}
```

Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: Where would I place onActivityResult() method. And how would I access this method.

Answer (score 1):

If u opened Activity A->B->C

You can use something like:

use 
`finish();` 
on Activity C

and use

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    reloadDATABASE();
}
```

on Activity B

Activity C will close and Activity B will reload its DATABASE

u can use the same method to close Activity B and reload Activity A

Answer (score -2):

Why you want to reload because actually activity B is already there in stack. So, just simply  call `closeActivity()` on Activity C and your activity B will be resumed.

Comment: may be to refresh some data?